# Can I create a class that can hold any kind of objects without me specifying class properties?

Tags: c#, class

Can I create a class that can hold any collection of objects for me ?

For example a collection of virtual directory ?

**Edit**

In reference to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315834/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-virtual-directory-of-one-web-application-to-another-web?noredirect=1#comment28635593_19315834.

I am trying to copy virtual directories from one site to another, but when I try to commit changes to server manager I get an error as it's readonly which I guess is because **I am reading values from it same time I want to write to it**.

Can I create a sub class for virtual directory object and store values in it? if yes then how?

This is smelling code I got at the moment,

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lstWebSitesCopyFrom.CheckedItems)
{
    using (var CopyFromMgr = new ServerManager())
    {
        foreach (var CopyFromsite in CopyFromMgr.Sites)
        {
            if (CopyFromsite.Name == item.Text)
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application CopyFromApp in CopyFromsite.Applications)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item2 in lstWebSitesCopyTo.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        using (var CopyToMgr = new ServerManager())
                        {
                            foreach (var CopyToSite in CopyToMgr.Sites)
                            {
                                if (CopyToSite.Name == item2.Text)
                                {
                                    foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application CopyToApp in CopyToSite.Applications)
                                    {
                                        int i = 0;

                                        foreach (VirtualDirectory oldVD in CopyFromApp.VirtualDirectories)
                                        {
                                            if (i == 0)
                                            {
                                                i++;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                CopyToApp.VirtualDirectories.Add(oldVD);
                                                CopyToMgr.CommitChanges();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your question as being too broad. Could you specify a little bit more?

Comment: `List<object>` technically.

Comment: Do You want JUST to have a container for ANY type of objects ?
Like it has a List<object> as the one and only property ?

Comment: Can you give a couple of pseudo-code (or C#) examples of what you're wanting to do? Preferably two distinct usages so which parts are common and which are distinct can be seen.

Comment: Out of ignorance, can't you just copy the files? Why not?

Comment: @LuisFilipe because it's duplication !!

Answer (score 2):

From you question i'd guess two options

**Generics**

Any collection from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, e.g,

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
```

Or from .net4.0+

**ExpandoObject**
which adds properties at runtime (much like Javascript does)

```
dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
obj.Name = "Stack";
```